# LinkedIn API Python Key Error 2.7

Tags: python, json, csv

This code is available online to run a map of your connections in linkedin
This uses linkedin api.
I'm able to connect fine and everything runs okay till the last script of actually writing the data to a csv.

Whenever I run the code

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urlparse
import simplejson
import codecs

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxx"
OAUTH_TOKEN = "xxx"
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxx"

OUTPUT = "linked.csv"

def linkedin_connections():

    # Use your credentials to build the oauth client
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
token = oauth.Token(key=OAUTH_TOKEN, secret=OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

# Fetch first degree connections
resp, content = client.request('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?format=json')
results = simplejson.loads(content)    

# File that will store the results
output = codecs.open(OUTPUT, 'w', 'utf-8')

# Loop thru the 1st degree connection and see how they connect to each other
for result in results["values"]:
    con = "%s %s" % (result["firstName"].replace(",", " "),    result["lastName"].replace(",", " "))
    print >>output, "%s,%s" % ("John Henry",  con)

# This is the trick, use the search API to get related connections
    u = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%s:(relation-to-viewer:(related-connections))?format=json" % result["id"]
    resp, content = client.request(u)
    rels = simplejson.loads(content)
try:
for rel in rels['relationToViewer']['relatedConnections']['values']:
    sec = "%s %s" % (rel["firstName"].replace(",", " "), rel["lastName"].replace(",", " "))
    print >>output, "%s,%s" % (con, sec)
except:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    linkedin_connections()     

for result in results["values"]:
    KeyError: 'values'
```

When I run this I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "linkedin-2-query.py", line 51, in <module>
linkedin_connections()
File "linkedin-2-query.py", line 35, in linkedin_connections
for result in results["values"]:
KeyError: 'values'
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your URL has a number of spaces in it, is that intentional or a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: Clearly, the JSON response has no `values` key; I suspect you may be looking for `connections` instead?

Comment: -Hi Martijn, the source has no spaces, thanks for spotting that in my the above.

Comment: Easiest way to see what is returned is by printing `result.keys()`; what does that give you for the API call result?

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you suggesting to change the word 'values' to 'connections' in the for loop?

Comment: Yes, I am. That's the main key for the XML response as documented in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When I change the word to connections I get the same keyerror message except change values for connections. The script above uses JSON, not XML

Comment: I only mentioned XML because that is what the LinkedIn docs use as examples. What does `print results.keys()` tell you is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue working through the post [Visualizing your LinkedIn graph using Gephi – Part 1](http://dataiku.com/visualizing-your-linkedin-graph-using-gephi-part-1/#comment-723).

> Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.   [KeyError - Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)

After searching a bit and adding some print statements, I realize that my OAuth session has expired, so the OAuth token in my [`linkedin-2-query.py`](https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/5744765) script was is longer valid.

Since the OAuth token is invalid, the LinkedIn API does not return a dictionary with the key `"values"` like the script expects.  Instead, the API returns the string `'N'`.  Python tries to find the dict key `"values"`in the string `'N'`, fails, and generates the `KeyError: 'values'`.

So a new, valid OAuth token & secret should get the API to return a dict containing connection data.

---

I run the [`linkedin-1-oauth.py`](https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/5744717) script again, and then visit the LinkedIn [Application details page](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) to find my new OAuth token. (The screenshot omits the values for my app. You should see alphanumeric values for each Key, Token, & Secret.)

[image]

**...**

[image]

I then update my [`linkedin-2-query.py`](https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/5744765) script with the new **OAuth User Token** and **OAuth User Secret**

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" # your updated OAuth User Token
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" # your updated OAuth User Secret
```

After updating the OAuth token & secret, I immediately run my [`linkedin-2-query.py`](https://gist.github.com/micahstubbs/5744765) script.  Hooray, it runs without errors and retrieves my connection data from the API.